# Gravity / Jumping ball in canvas, javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, gravity

My project is to create a game, ball which should be jumping on a keypress, go left and right. My problem is, that the gravity I have implemented into that game brought me a problem. The ball is stuck in the ground, which is a picture on the bottom of my canvas. It is stuck because of wrong collision code, I guess.

Question is, if you can help me with solving this problem and maybe give a a hint how to continue, because I tried to find which collision is making that problem but I found nothing.

Link to that game is here: [Game](http://www.slovenskaves.sk/febeks/game/game.html)
JSFiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0pvdunsh/1/)

Code where the players collision is located /other codes are working as they should so I am not going to put them here, only if you will really need them/

```
       function Player(x, y) {
     var size = 70;
      GameObject.call(this, x, y, size);
      this.img = document.getElementById("lopta");
      this.rotation = 0;
      this.dx = Math.random() * 50 - 25;
      this.dy = Math.random() * 50 - 25;

}

// Dedi vlastnosti z GameObject
Player.prototype = Object.create(GameObject.prototype);

Player.prototype.move = function(dt) {

    var x = this.x;
    var y = this.y;

    var sirka = canvas.width;
    var vyska = canvas.height;
    var bounce = 0.6;
 // Gravitacia
    this.dy += 9.8 * dt;

    // Posun
    if ( keys[37] ) {
        this.rotation -= dt;
        x-=5;
    }
    if ( keys[39] ) {
        this.rotation += dt;
        x+=5;
    }
    if ( keys[38] ) y-=5;
    if ( keys[40] ) y+=5;


        // Test novej pozicie
    var collision = false;
    for (i in scene) {
      var obj = scene[i];
      var test = 

                x -35>= obj.x + obj.size || 
                x + this.size -35<= obj.x || 
                y -35>= obj.y + obj.size ||
                this.dy - 35 >= obj.dy + obj.size || 
                y + this.size -35 <= obj.y ||
                this.dy + this.size -35<= obj.dy; 
      if (!test) {
        collision = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    // Posun bez kolizie
    if (!collision) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
    }
    // Posun
      //this.x += this.dx * dt;
    this.y += this.dy * dt;


    // podmienky aby lopta nevysla z hracieho pola cize z canvasu
    if (this.x + this.size - 35> canvas.width) {
        this.x  = canvas.width - this.size +35;

      }
      if (this.x -35 < 0) {
        this.x = 35;
      }

      if (this.y+this.size - 35 > canvas.height) {
        this.y = canvas.height - this.size + 35;

        this.dy *= -bounce;
        if(this.dy * (-bounce)  <   4)
            this.dy = 0;
      }
      if (this.y - 35< 0) {
        this.y = 35;    
      };


};

Player.prototype.draw = function() {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);
    ctx.rotate(this.rotation);
    ctx.translate(-35, -35);
    //ctx.scale(this.size,this.size);
    ctx.drawImage(this.img, 0, 0, this.size, this.size);
    ctx.restore();

    };
```

Comment: If you make a working http://jsfiddle.net, it would help.

Comment: I tried to but there is more files and I dont know how to add them all together so it will work.

Comment: There's the External Resources option on the left, or you can [hack the CSS pane](http://jsfiddle.net/zfagfw7h/).

Comment: Updated with external resources, see above :)

Answer (score 1):

First, Pardon me for not totally understanding what your asking.

If you're having problems detecting collisions between the ball & brick-rects  or the ball & walls, here are some useful utility functions for you:

```
// Given circle & rect definitions
var circle={x:50,y:50,r:25};
var rect={x:125,y:125,w:50,h:50};


// detect if circle & rect are colliding
function RectCircleColliding(circle,rect){
    var distX = Math.abs(circle.x - rect.x-rect.w/2);
    var distY = Math.abs(circle.y - rect.y-rect.h/2);
    if (distX > (rect.w/2 + circle.r)) { return false; }
    if (distY > (rect.h/2 + circle.r)) { return false; }
    if (distX <= (rect.w/2)) { return true; } 
    if (distY <= (rect.h/2)) { return true; }
    var dx=distX-rect.w/2;
    var dy=distY-rect.h/2;
    return (dx*dx+dy*dy<=(circle.r*circle.r));
}

// detect if circle is colliding with canvas sides
function CircleWallColliding(circle){
    var cx=circle.x;
    var cy=circle.y;
    var r=circle.r;
    if(cx-r<0 || cx+r>canvas.width || cy-r<0 || cy+r>canvas.height){return(true);}
    return(false);
}
```

**Example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
  var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  offsetX=BB.left;
  offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }

ctx.lineWidth=3;

var isDown=false;
var startX,startY;

var circle={x:50,y:50,r:25};
var rect={x:125,y:125,w:50,h:50};

$("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});

draw('green');

function draw(circleFill){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);

  ctx.fillStyle='blue';
  ctx.fillRect(rect.x,rect.y,rect.w,rect.h);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(circle.x,circle.y,circle.r,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle=circleFill;
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
}


function handleMouseMove(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  circle.x=mouseX;
  circle.y=mouseY;

  var isColliding=RectCircleColliding(circle,rect)||CircleWallColliding(circle);
  draw(isColliding?'red':'green');

}

// detect if circle & rect are colliding
function RectCircleColliding(circle,rect){
  var distX = Math.abs(circle.x - rect.x-rect.w/2);
  var distY = Math.abs(circle.y - rect.y-rect.h/2);
  if (distX > (rect.w/2 + circle.r)) { return false; }
  if (distY > (rect.h/2 + circle.r)) { return false; }
  if (distX <= (rect.w/2)) { return true; } 
  if (distY <= (rect.h/2)) { return true; }
  var dx=distX-rect.w/2;
  var dy=distY-rect.h/2;
  return (dx*dx+dy*dy<=(circle.r*circle.r));
}

// detect if circle is colliding with canvas sides
function CircleWallColliding(circle){
  var cx=circle.x;
  var cy=circle.y;
  var r=circle.r;
  if(cx-r<0 || cx+r>canvas.width || cy-r<0 || cy+r>canvas.height){return(true);}
  return(false);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Move ball with mouse.<br>Ball turns red if colling with rect or wall.</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things I'm noticing. First, you separated your colliding movement logic from your bouncing logic, so the ball can essentially fall straight through objects. From what I can tell, objects only block manual movement. Also, said manual movement ignores `dt`, so the speed of it can vary with framerate.

Anyway, a breakpoint set on the line `collision = true;` reveals the problem: One of your scene's objects does not have a size set, which causes `obj.x + obj.size` and `obj.y + obj.size` to return `NaN` which is like infinity. You have several such, actually: It's the grass object.

So here are your choices: Either don't make the grass a part of the scene (It shouldn't participate in collision anyway), and instead change the rendering logic to use a separate object array from the collision logic (as would make sense), or set `size = 0;` for the grass.

Comment: thanks, I was thinking about separation of colliding movement with bouncing logic but I am not sure how can I fix it, I am just a beginner in Javascript. Would you mind if I ask you for some hints (editing my code a little with comments where needed?) Thanks again.

Comment: It's not separation you need, but rather fusion. Movement logic and collision should be combined. The first step to this is to change the part where you change `x` and `y` based on the keys with setting `dx` and `dy` instead, so the keys determine the ball's speed.

Comment: Next step would be to change the collision so instead of simply stopping in place if the ball is trying to move into an object, it tries to do something smarter. For instance, you can retry the movement without the `dx` factor. If this still doesn't work, try reversing `dy` and try again, to simulate bouncing off of any object. You should try movements in this order: Same dy, dx=0; dy=-dy, same dx; dy=-dy, dx=0. If none work, make the ball stay still.

Comment: I did change x y to dx dy but I dont know how to do the next step. I am confused with using dx and dy.

Comment: You're already halfway there in the code you've posted. `this.y += this.dy*dt;` is the right formula, but doesn't include collision. What you need is `x = this.x+this.dx*dt; y = this.y+this.dy*dt; if (!check_collision(x, y)) { this.x = x; this.y = y; }`. Then, to check for possible bounce, you can add `else { y = this.y-this.dy*dt; if (!check_colllision(x, y)) { this.x = x; this.y = y; this.dy = - this.dy; }`. Then, you can add a few extra cases for checking a collision in the `x` direction.

Comment: Your scene still contains the grass objects. What you can do is set up two arrays. "scene" will contain all objects, and be used for rendering. "collision_scene" will contain only the blocks. Then use "collision_scene" when checking the collision.

Comment: Additionally, you can't precalculate the collision, and then re-use the value after changing `x` and `y`. Make a function that checks the collision for `x` and `y`, and call it every time you change their values. Otherwise, checking `collision` several times is meaningless. Finally, add the collision check with the ground to the main collision check, instead of having it as a separate code below.

Comment: I have moved on with some things as you can see if you try to play the game, but my problem is now that the ball is stuck in the object when collision takes place...What am I doing wrong there?

Comment: It's actually working surprisingly well for me. But there are still a few issues. First, you still calculate collision with the ground and borders (player.js, line 99) separately from calculating regular collisions (player.js, line 47). A possible change here is to move line 99-116 up to above line 77, then replace the bounce handling (Lines 104, 110, 115) simply to "collision = true;". This means that collision with an object will use the same code as collision with the ground and borders

Comment: The second issue I see is that you don't re-check collision after changing `dx` and `dy` in lines 86-87. First, setting `dx = x` is wrong. At most, it should be `dx = 0`. Second, after changing `dy` you should recalculate `x` and `y` as you do in lines 41-42, and then recalculate the collision as you do in lines 44-75. BUT, don't copy-paste the whole code for collision detection. Instead, put it inside a function, like so: `var collision; function recheck_collision() {collision = false; /* Lines 47-75 go here */} recheck_collision();`